# MCU Design, maximum wire length per frequency and characteristic

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, emc, emi-filtering

I'm getting pretty deep into MCU design and I've run into a problem for which I'd like to find a formula.

In circuit path design how can I correlate max wire length to max transmission frequency on that wire/pin?

I'm working with a wide assortment of MCUs and external hardware operating range 16MHz to 160MHz.

For example:
I have a 20MIPS MPU interfaced with an SRAM (parallel) IC. The SRAM has a 10ns access speed which is more than enough speed for the MPU. The MPU takes two intsructions one to write the address and one to read/write the data. The data and addresses are on separate buses so the maximum speed on any given pin in the project is 10MHz.
Currently that works just fine with a 4" ribbon wire for each bus, but I'm concerned that If I swap out MCUs for a 48MIPS or 72MIPS MCU that I will have timing issues.

I read this thread and a few others, but they appear to be mostly single use fixes, where I need a general formula if possible. [Wire length, EMI and comms failures](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/324969/wire-length-emi-and-comms-failures)

Followup question, does it matter if the signal is part of a parallel or serial bus, or can each pin simply be examined as a single entity?

Alternately acceptable to a formula would be some good reading material on this specific topic.

I also recognize that using larger gauge wire, twisted pair for serial, adding a ground line(s) for noise, and using pull-ups/downs may help the issue. For this question though my primary focus is length v frequency, if that's possible.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: There are two heuristics often quoted: propagation speed of about 1 nanosecond per foot (30cm), and that a wire should be considered as a transmission line when its length is more than 10% of the wavelength of the signal.

Comment: Some of what you are trying to do would simply not be considered economically viable today - situations where it makes sense to interface a modern CPU to external SRAM are rare.  Typically you would use an MCU with more on-chip RAM, use a cheap processor with on-chip cache and large cheap external DDR, or put the whole thing in an FPGA perhaps backed by external DDR for the larger/slower part.

Comment: @Chris Strantton I appreciate the advise, but this is what I'm working on.

Comment: Stratton, please excuse my typo

Comment: @pjc50 the 1ns per foot note is exactly what I am looking for, Thanks. I am reading about transmission lines and calculating wavelengths now.

Comment: @Mikeologist bonus 2 minute video of Admiral Hopper explaining the nanosecond: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEpsKnWZrJ8

Comment: It must be a matched impedance for maximum BW otherwise ringing …

Answer (score 1):

There really is no general formula that's going to work in all cases. For starters, the upper bound on propagation speed is going to be the speed of light. However, the speed at which a signal propagates down a wire depends on the dielectric (insulation) around the wire. For a bare wire, this will be air and signals will travel at close to light speed. For traces on a circuit board, signals will travel at around half of light speed. Next, you need to know if the signal is actually propagating as an electromagnetic wave or if you're RC limited. This will depend on the length of the wire, the resistance of the wire, the distance from the ground plane or other conductors, etc. And then you have to look at reflections. If your wire is not a transmission line with matched impedance on at least one end, you're going to get reflections and you're going to have to wait several propagation delays for the reflections to die down before you'll be able to reliably recover the signal level.  And that doesn't even consider crosstalk/coupling from adjacent signals.

Comment: All great stuff. Thank you. Expanding my reading list as we speak.